# ReliableQueue item hasvalue but value is null

Tags: .net, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm running into an issue with service fabric where, in my runAsync method, eventually, all items coming from an inbox queue (an instance of IReliableQueue) become null.

The RunAsync method is able to complete an arbitrary number of values before this occurs. 
We've tried executing the code synchronously as well as garbage collecting after every request in the currentProcessingQueue finishes.

Has anyone encountered something similar before?

---

```
                        if (queueSize < MaximumCurrentProcessingQueueLength)
                        {
                            var inboxResult = await inboxQueue.TryDequeueAsync(tx, DefaultReliableCollectionsTimeout, cancellationToken);
                            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                            if (inboxResult.HasValue)
                            {
                                dequeueFromInboxCount++;
                                if (inboxResult.Value == null) throw new Exception("result has value was true, but value was null");
                                await currentProcessingQueue.EnqueueAsync(tx, inboxResult.Value);
```

---

Comment: Stupid question: Are you by any chance inserting null values into the queue at some point? Do you check for that?

Comment: We're definitely not inserting null values into the queue.  We even added a check right after the initialization of the value being inserted in to ensure the item is not null. And the size of the queue seems to stay correct, it's just that every value is null

Comment: OK thanks. Is there any noticeable pattern to this, for example, does it happen after a certain amount of time, after a certain number of items in the queue, after a failover event (replicas moving after an upgrade, failure, or for balancing)? Is there anywhere in your code where you modify references to enqueued items outside of a transaction? Is the problem reproducible consistently in each new deployment of the service? Are you using any custom serializers?

Comment: Oops, forgot to update this question. The issue seemed to be we had a reliable dictionary as well, and when we inserted an item that was too large, the queue could not be replicated successfully, and while it preserved the queue count, it did not properly preserve the queue objects and when you tried to access it it became null. We solved it by compressing items before putting them into the dictionary